# How to make clang-format not align parameters to function call?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to make clang-format not align call parameters to the '(' symbol. I had tried setting `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter` to 0, but it didn't help.

How I want it to be:

```cpp
veeeeeeeryLongFunctionName(
    longParameter1, longParameter2,
    longParameter3, longParameter4
)

// or

veeeeeeeryLongFunctionName(
    loooooooooongParameter1,
    loooooooooongParameter2,
    loooooooooongParameter3,
    loooooooooongParameter4
)
```

How clang-format does it:

```cpp
veeeeeeeryLongFunctionName(loooooooooongParameter1,
                           loooooooooongParameter2,
                           loooooooooongParameter3,
                           loooooooooongParameter4
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket : BlockIndent
```

> Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line. Closing brackets will be placed on a new line. E.g.:
>
> ```
> someLongFunction(
>    argument1, argument2
> )
> ```

[Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)